# System Preferences search no longer highlights possible matches

Tags: macos, system-settings, highlights

Spotlight would mark matches when searching in system preferences are no longer appearing. I have "System Preferences" enabled in Spotlight prefs. I have searched for a solution to this, no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Screencapture showing the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/juc58rpqnuztr3w/system-prefs.mov?dl=0)

[image: Spotlight preferences]

Answer (score 1):

How long have you waited since checking the box?  It can take some to re-index.  Or you may need to force a re-indexing.  You can do this in terminal by deleting the index and rebuilding it.  This may take a while.  Go to Terminal in Utilities folder and cut/paste this into the command line:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

Comment: I actually never unchecked that option. Still, I did rebuild the index (waited for the indexing to finish) but the problem is still there.